# Obstruction to deforming vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, quantization

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety and let $D$ denote any $\mathbb C[[h]]$-deformation of $\mathcal O_X$. Suppose that $D$ is trivial. Then it is well-known that obstructions to deforming any $X$-vector bundle $\mathcal F$ to $D/h^n$ lie in the space $Ext^2(F, F)$.

Does this result still hold for non-trivial $D$?

Comment: Yes, with the same proof.